# Tool bar button color doesn't display properly

Tags: vb.net

The project used to be created by using .net 1.0 and now i have upgraded it into .net4.0. I'm facing an issue when i try to change whatever image in the toolbar icon, the antialiasing grey border will all become black color. Anyone have faced this before & is there any solution for this because I have tried all the properties & seems like no solution so far. [image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of toolbar (control object) is it?  If I remember rightly, MS 'upgraded' the default toolbar control a few versions of the Framework ago.

Comment: it's called as System.Forms.ToolBar, i have tried to use the latest version of control (System.Forms.ToolStrip) and it overcome the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's called as System.Forms.ToolBar, i have tried to use the latest version of control (System.Forms.ToolStrip) and it overcome the problem :) –